# Model binding on GET request using Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetAll(GetItemRequest request) {
```

This throws an error, *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*, where `request` is null.

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetAll(int itemId) {
```

This works just fine, where `itemId` is non-null.

`GetItemRequest` model has a single property, `public int itemId { get; set; }`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetAll([FromUri] GetItemRequest request) {
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still receive the same error. It comes in as `null` still.

Comment: Sorry - that was poor advice - I missed that you were doing a GET. See Edit - need FromUri instead of FromBody